# Retrieving data in AngularJS "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Im working in laravel and i start to implement angular to my frontend.

This is the route:

```
Route::get('test', 'WorkController@inicio');
```

My controller function:

```
public function inicio()
{
    $works = new Work;
    $works = Work::Paginate(10);
    return view('test', compact('works'));
}
```

And the view where i what to display the database information.

```
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <link href="/css/lib.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>test</h1>
    <h2>test</h2>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController as controller">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="datos in data">
                <a class="floating-box">@{{datos.client}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <hr/>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
    app.controller("myController", function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.buscador = '';
        $http.get("<?=env('APP_URL')?>" + '/test').then(function(datos) {
            console.log(datos.data.data);
            $scope.data = datos.data.data;
            console.log($scope.data);
        })
    });
</script>
```

But then i get this in console:

> GET http://localhost/test net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

and the information isnt in the view.

Comment: Have you checked if your sever is running?

Comment: Yes, it give me the page but without information. And show me the problem in the browser console.

Comment: Remove the angular tag - that's reserved for angular 2+ And normally this relates to authentication issues/missing credentials. Basic Auth http headers missing etc

Comment: got this **(2/2) ErrorException
Use of undefined constant datos - assumed 'datos' (View: C:\Users\Luis\mongolaravel\mongodb\resources\views\test.blade.php)**